# Understanding scope and jquery chaining in javascript

Tags: jquery, scope, chaining

I am trying to better understand scope and chaining in javascript.  I have the following which works just fine

```
$("div.sked, div.report, div.database").hover (function (){
     let $this = $(this);
     let $pos = $this.position();
     $submenu = $this.find (":first-child");
     $submenu.css ('left', $pos.left + 30);
     $submenu.css ('top', $top);
     $submenu.show();
     })
     .mouseleave  (function (){
     $submenu.hide();
 });
```

But when I add a `let` before `$submenu = $this.find (":first-child");`
Then `$submenu` goes out of scope and submenus are not hidden.

I would like top understand the proper way to code this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

That's because `let` variables are block scoped, and not are function scoped. If you declare the variable in the first callback, you cannot use it in the other callback because the block has been changed.

To share a variable among the two functions, you will need to declare it at a place which makes it available to both of the scopes.

But, in your case, there is no such place as event handlers can be executed irrespective of their declared order. So, you will need to fetch the element again in the `mouseleave`'s callback.

```
$("div.sked, div.report, div.database").hover(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let $pos = $this.position();
    $submenu = $this.find(":first-child");
    $submenu.css('left', $pos.left + 30);
    $submenu.css('top', $top);
    $submenu.show();
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    $submenu = $this.find(":first-child");
    $submenu.hide();
  });
```